# How to move first digit to the last position in a number in C

Tags: c, integer, digits

Let's take the number 123 for example. How would I move the 1 so that the resulting number is 231?

```
unsigned long int N;
scanf("%lu", &N);
unsigned long int firstDigit;
while (N >= 10)
{  
  N /= 10;
  firstDigit = N;
  count++;
}
```

I have this code to identify what the first digit is, but now I don't know how I would move it.

Comment: Now that you've got the first digit, multiply it by 10 enough times so that it's in the correct position (`count` will be useful here), and then subtract it from `N`. For example, if `N` is 123, then `firstDigit` is 1, and `count` should be 2. Multiply 1 by 10 twice to get 100. Subtract from 123 to get 23. The rest is easy.

Comment: I would do this with strings

Comment: Can be done both ways, depends on the requirement of the assignment. (though I agree using a string makes it much easier). Numerically, after finding the 1st digit, you will need to subtract `10^(count-1) * digit` from `N` and then multiply by `10` and add `digit`.

Comment: If the input was `000123`, should the result be `001230` or `231`?

Answer (score 1):

by while loop, we get a number excluding the first digit (in `ans` variable) &
only the first digit of a given number (in 'N' variable).

```
unsigned long int N;
scanf("%lu", &N); // N=1234
unsigned long int ans=0;
unsigned long int pow=1;
while (N>9) {
    ans += pow * (N%10);
    pow *= 10;
    N /= 10;
}  // ans=234  N=1

ans = ans*10 + N;
```

what's the value of a variable after execution:-

```
 |     condition     | ans       | pow  | N     |
 | ----------------- | --------- | ---- | ----- |
 |   before loop     | 0         | 1    | 1234  |
 |     1234 > 9      | 4         | 10   | 123   |
 |      123 > 9      | 34        | 100  | 12    |
 |       12 > 9      | 234       | 1000 | 1     |
 | 1 ≯ 9 (loop over) |           |      |       |
 |    after loop     | ans = 234 |      | N = 1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `N = 546` and obtained `firstDigit = 5`. So to move firstDigit to the last position first you have to remove the firstDigit from **N**. If `count = number of digits of N` then `N - (firstDigit * 10^(count-1))` will give the number without firstDigit. For N = 546 you will get `removedFirstDigit = 46`. So then you just have to attach firstDigit to the last position using `10 * removedFirstDigit + firstDigit` to get the final answer. Follow that code for better understanding,

```
unsigned long int N;
scanf("%lu", &N);
unsigned long int value = N;
unsigned long int firstDigit;
int count = 0;
while (N >= 10)
{  
  N /= 10;
  firstDigit = N;
  count++;
}

unsigned long int powerOfTen = 1;
for(int i=1; i<=count; i++) {
    powerOfTen *= 10;
}

unsigned long int removedFirstDigit = value - (firstDigit * powerOfTen);
unsigned long int ans = 10 * removedFirstDigit + firstDigit;

printf("%lu", ans);
```

You can also solve this problem by converting the number into string and just moving the first character to the last position.

Answer (score 0):

How about another view. We will consider with string operation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
  int main()
  {
     char i[10]="";
     scanf ("%s", &i);
     for (int j = 1; i[j] != NULL; j++)
      printf ("%c",i[j]);
      printf ("%c\n",i[0]);
     return 0;
  }
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

### It's a Solution Without Using Loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    unsigned long int length = 0;
    unsigned long int ans = 0;
    
    unsigned long int number;
    scanf("%lu", &number);   // number = 9731
    
    length = log10(number);
    
    unsigned long int power = pow(10,length);
    ans = (number%power)*10  +  number/power; // 7319
    
    printf("%lu %lu %lu %lu", number, length, power, ans);
}
```

number : Input Data
length : log base 10 will give ((size of number) - 1)
power : 10<sup>length</sup>

for get ans:

- took first digit by (number / power)                  `// got only 9`
- took rest of digits by (number % power)              `// got 731`
- before adding those both, should remove overlapping `// 9 & 1`
  - so rest of digits should transfer left                `//731* from 731`
  - for that multiply it with 10                         `// 731 become 7310`
- add both data                                     `// 7310 + 9`